# How to debug open telemetry java agent extension instrumentation?

Tags: java, instrumentation, byte-buddy, open-telemetry

I am trying to follow [the open telemetry auto instrumentation java agent extension](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/main/examples/extension/README.md) and I have come up with the following instrumentation code:

```java
/*
 * Copyright The OpenTelemetry Authors
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 */

package com.example.javaagent.instrumentation;

import static io.opentelemetry.api.common.AttributeKey.stringKey;
import static net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers.namedOneOf;

import io.opentelemetry.api.GlobalOpenTelemetry;
import io.opentelemetry.api.OpenTelemetry;
import io.opentelemetry.api.common.Attributes;
import io.opentelemetry.api.metrics.Meter;
import io.opentelemetry.api.metrics.ObservableLongMeasurement;
import io.opentelemetry.javaagent.extension.instrumentation.TypeInstrumentation;
import io.opentelemetry.javaagent.extension.instrumentation.TypeTransformer;
import io.opentelemetry.javaagent.extension.matcher.AgentElementMatchers;
import net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice;
import net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription;
import net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatcher;

public class DemoHelloWorldInstrumentation implements TypeInstrumentation {

  private static String CLASS_NAME = "my.package.MyClass";

  private static OpenTelemetry telemetry = GlobalOpenTelemetry.get();

  private static Meter meter = telemetry.getMeterProvider().meterBuilder(CLASS_NAME).build();

  private static ObservableLongMeasurement click =
      meter
          .counterBuilder("click")
          .setUnit("counter")
          .setDescription("Number of click")
          .buildObserver();
  ;

  static {
    meter.batchCallback(
        () -> {
          click.record(1, Attributes.of(stringKey("none"), "none"));
        },
        click);
  }

  @Override
  public ElementMatcher<TypeDescription> typeMatcher() {
    return AgentElementMatchers.hasSuperType(namedOneOf(CLASS_NAME));
  }

  @Override
  public void transform(TypeTransformer typeTransformer) {
    typeTransformer.applyAdviceToMethod(
        namedOneOf("sayHello"), this.getClass().getName() + "$GreetingAdvice");
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
  public static class GreetingAdvice {

    @Advice.OnMethodEnter(suppress = Throwable.class)
    public static void onEnter(@Advice.Argument(value = 0) String name) {
      System.out.println("inst name = " + name);
      click.record(1, Attributes.of(stringKey("name"), name));
    }
  }
}
```

I am expecting some metrics would be exported with name = `click` but neither the metrics get exported nor `println` output anything in stdout.  I have checked and made sure the namings are correct.  It seems to build ok inside the open telemetry extension project and I could reference it using the `-Dotel.javaagent.extensions=/path/to/my/extension.jar` to run the app , when I hit the endpoint it seems to work and other metrics are exported.  Anyone got any suggestion on how to debug this or if you know what I have done wrong pls let me know thank you!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using the [javaagent debug mode](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/java/automatic/#troubleshooting)? It's very verbose, but should print some useful output.

You should not put any state or dependencies into the `TypeInstrumentation` class (neither into the advice class). In the OTel javaagent, the agent code is inaccessible from the application code; all code that is supposed to be injected into the application code must be kept in separate classes. The `telemetry`, `meter`, `click` fields that you have in your  `TypeInstrumentation` implementation are simply not visible from your advice class. I'd advice extracting all logic to a separate helper class, and just call that class from the advice.

See https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/main/docs/contributing/writing-instrumentation-module.md#use-advice-classes-to-write-code-that-will-get-injected-to-the-instrumented-library-classes for a more detailed explanation on how to correctly implement an `InstrumentationModule`, `TypeInstrumentation`s and advice classes.

Other than that, the `buildObserver()` and `ObservableLongMeasurement` are only supposed to be used within a `BatchCallback`. It will not register anything if you call it directly in the advice class; use `build()` and `LongCounter` instead.

Comment: Thank you @Mateusz Rzeszutek there are quite a few things you have suggested - I will try them out and report back

Comment: Sure! One more thing that you'll probably need is the [`isHelperClass()`](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/main/docs/contributing/writing-instrumentation-module.md#tell-the-agent-which-classes-are-a-part-of-the-instrumentation-by-overriding-the-ishelperclass-method) method; in case you add a helper class that needs to be injected you'll have to use that method to tell the agent about that class.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `InstrumentationModule` where your `DemoHelloWorldInstrumentation` class should be mentioned:

```
@AutoService(InstrumentationModule.class)
public class Module extends InstrumentationModule {

    public Module() {
        super("some-name");
    }

    @Override
    public List<TypeInstrumentation> typeInstrumentations() {
        return List.of(
                new DemoHelloWorldInstrumentation());
    }

}
```